# H2 Composite Primary Key (fields get unique but not primary key)

Tags: database, primary-key, h2, composite-primary-key

I have a problem with a composite primary key in my h2 database table.
This is the create statement of the table:

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TTColumn (  
    Name VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,  
    TTName CHAR(8) NOT NULL,  
    Type VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,  
    Length INTEGER NOT NULL,  
    Position INTEGER NOT NULL,  
    IsDBLogType BIT NOT NULL,   
    PRIMARY KEY(TTName,Name),   
    FOREIGN KEY(TTName) REFERENCES TrackingTable(Name))
```

(TTName is the name of the table for the columns, so its the same for each column of the table, but each column is unique in a table so its an composite key)
If i fill this table with data, i get the following exception

```
rg.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Eindeutiger Index oder Primärschlüssel verletzt: "CONSTRAINT_INDEX_E8 ON PUBLIC.TTCOLUMN(TTNAME) VALUES ('KIBLCOVI', 1)"
Unique index or primary key violation: "CONSTRAINT_INDEX_E8 ON PUBLIC.TTCOLUMN(TTNAME) VALUES ('KIBLCOVI', 1)"; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO TTColumn (Name,TTName,Type,Length,Position,IsDBLogType) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?) [23505-189]
```

As you can see the column "Name" is not part of the primary key anymore, like i defined in the create statement and i dont know why.
I have this problem in other tables too and adding the primary with alter table, after creating it, resolves in the same problem. When "Name" is the first column in the primary key, it gets the only column in the primary key, so the last entrys get removed.

I know, one solution would be to use id's, but I want to use a composite primary key, because i hate to add id's when its not necessary.
Is there something wrong with my create statement or do you have any other hints?

P.s. i tried the Version 1.4.189 and Version 1.3.176 as .jar (no server)

Edit:
Hmm, following the output from show columns:

```
NAME|VARCHAR(15)|NO|UNI|NULL|  
TTNAME|CHAR(8)|NO|UNI|NULL|  
TYPE|VARCHAR(15)|NO||NULL|  
LENGTH|INTEGER(10)|NO||NULL|  
POSITION|INTEGER(10)|NO||NULL|  
ISDBLOGTYPE|BOOLEAN(1)|NO||NULL|
```

Somehow the column Name and TTName are UNI (Unique) but not a primary key.
if i change the order in the primary key declaration, the column TTName becomes a primary key field, but Name stays unique.